# How can I target a specific div with onClick?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a NetFlix clone main page.
I have already the list of movies,tv series ecc.. rendered horizontal.

I'd like to click on the next arrow and slide only the relative section.
Now if I click the next arrow on the first section, the second one above scroll and I don't want that..

How can I achieve it?

I tried to google it and some tutorials but I can't find how to target elements in the same parent with onClick.

Thank you very much

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { moviesNow: [], tvSeries: [], actionMovies: [], animation: [] };

  containerSection = React.createRef();

  handleClick = e => {
    this.containerSection.current.style.transform = `translateX(-100%)`;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">

        <h1 className="section-title">Now playing</h1>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="nextArrow" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <img src={nextArrow} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div ref={this.containerSection} className="container-section">
            <MovieItem movies={this.state.moviesNow} />
          </div>
        </div>

        <h1 className="section-title">TV Series</h1>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="nextArrow" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <img src={nextArrow} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div ref={this.containerSection} className="container-section">
            <MovieItem movies={this.state.tvSeries} />
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using only one `ref` for two different elements, I guess that is where you issue is coming from. So I updated `handleClick` to be able to receive a `ref` as an argument and return a function that will receive the event :

```
  handleClick = ref => e => {
    ref.current.style.transform = `translateX(-100%)`;
  };
```

Then you can use `handleClick` this way:

```
   <div className="nextArrow" onClick={this.handleClick(secondContainerSection)}>
     <img src={nextArrow} alt="" />
   </div>
```

Eventually it gives you something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { moviesNow: [], tvSeries: [], actionMovies: [], animation: [] };

  containerSection = React.createRef();
  //a new ref
  secondContainerSection = React.createRef();

  handleClick = ref => e => {
    ref.current.style.transform = `translateX(-100%)`;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">

        <h1 className="section-title">Now playing</h1>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="nextArrow" onClick={this.handleClick(containerSection)}>
            <img src={nextArrow} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div ref={this.containerSection} className="container-section">
            <MovieItem movies={this.state.moviesNow} />
          </div>
        </div>

        <h1 className="section-title">TV Series</h1>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="nextArrow" onClick={this.handleClick(secondContainerSection)}>
            <img src={nextArrow} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div ref={this.secondContainerSection} className="container-section">
            <MovieItem movies={this.state.tvSeries} />
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Is there any difference to write the function like this?
handleClick = (ref , e) => {
    ref.current.style.transform = `translateX(-100%)`;
  };

Answer (score 0):

make a seperate component for drawer and define the ref inside it

drawer Component

```
class Drawer extends React.Component {
  containerSection =new React.createRef();
  handleClick = e => {
    this.containerSection.current.style.transform = `translateX(-100%)`;
  };
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="nextArrow" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <img src={nextArrow} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div ref={this.containerSection} className="container-section">
          {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
```

Main component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { moviesNow: [], tvSeries: [], actionMovies: [], animation: [] };
  containerSection = React.createRef();
  handleClick = e => {
    this.containerSection.current.style.transform = `translateX(-100%)`;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="section-title">Now playing</h1>
    <Drawer><MovieItem movies={this.state.moviesNow} /></Drawer>

        <h1 className="section-title">TV Series</h1>
    <Drawer><MovieItem movies={this.state.tvSeries} /></Drawer>
        </div>);
```